# PHP cURL to grab Walmart Gift Cards Balance?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use the following the code to grab the balance in a gift card without using the walmart for enduser.

```
<?php 
$url = "https://www.walmart.com/cservice/ProcessShoppingCard.do";
//
$h = curl_init();

curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'cardNumber' => '1234567890123456',
'pin' => '1234',
'GetCardBalance' => 'GetCardBalance'
));
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($h);
echo $result;


?>
```

But it seems to only show the page and not the results. I examined the form used in walmart and it has only 3 fields: cardNumber, pin and GetCardBalance.

Which i have used but still not getting the results.

If i go to this url https://www.walmart.com/cservice/ProcessShoppingCard.do
And try to check the balance, it does show the response.

Any ideas, what and where i am doing wrong?

Please advice, 
thanks!

Comment: that's because you're fetching a url whose output is intended for human consumption. unless walmart provides a url which returns ONLY the balance, you'll have to use DOM operations to extract the balance from that "for humans only" html page.

Comment: Are you logged in to the site? Even if not it might be using session variables in addition to the form.

Comment: Try the mobile-website. They serve static versions, as opposed to the dynamic content served by full-webpages.

Comment: This isn't going to work unless you can figure out exactly how that form is being submitted. The "submit" button isn't really a submit button at all, it is an input element and it is relying on javascript for the form to be really submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of tries, i finally got able to use the following code to work.
I was not using POSTFIELDS method properly.
And i used Firefox Firebug to see what variables are being sent when submitting a form and used them according and it all worked :)

```
$url = "https://www.walmart.com/cservice/ProcessShoppingCard.do";
//
$h = curl_init();
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cardNumber=1234567890123456&pin=1234&GetCardBalance.x=90&GetCardBalance.y=8");
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//
$result = curl_exec($h);
echo $result;
```

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.